# What is the name of the current Lieutenant Governor of Virginia?

Tags: united-states, governor, virginia

Is the Lieutenant Governor of Virginia named "Winsome Sears" or "Winsome Earle-Sears"?

Her [official government web site](https://www.ltgov.virginia.gov/) lists her last name as "Earle-Sears", but her [campaign website](https://www.winsomesears.com/)'s address is "winsomesears.com". Her [Twitter name](https://twitter.com/WinsomeSears) is "Lt. Governor of Virginia - Winsome Earle-Sears", but her handle is @WinsomeSears. Her [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winsome_Sears) is titled "Winsome Sears", but the body of the article calls her "Winsome Earle-Sears". About half of news reports seem to refer to her as "Sears" and about half as "Earle-Sears".

So what is her last name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Earle is her maiden name, and Sears is her husband's name.  Like many women she sometimes uses a double-barreled last name "Earle-Sears" or "Earle Sears" and sometimes drops her maiden name.

Another political example was Cherie Booth Blair, (wife of Tony Blair) who uses "Booth" in her professional life (as a lawyer), and Blair in her political life.